# Simple print statement is not working in python .py when converted to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, printing, pyinstaller, exe

Python file contains one line print statement

```
#file1.py
print("python to exe")
```

Converted the .py file to .exe using pyinstaller Library in the windows environment successfully and got the executable file *'file1.exe'*

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w 'file1.py'
```

Tried executing the ***'file1.exe'*** in the command line prompt, the .exe neither prints nor shows any error. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using the "-w" option. On Windows this will disable the console window when running the program. From the pyinstaller documentation:

```
-w, --windowed, --noconsole

    Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS X this also triggers building an OS X .app bundle. On Windows this option will be set if the first script is a ‘.pyw’ file. This option is ignored in *NIX systems
```